# Intellij does not find runtime dependency included in gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies, build.gradle

I am using custom native libraries. It is included in gradle and gets downloaded correctly in the external libraries. However any commands that are in this library error out because the library cannot be found. Below is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "repo_URL"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'libName.jar'
    testRuntime 'libName.so'
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

The product API is in libName.jar which call secondary commands in libName.so. While both are correctly included in the External Libraries, I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error : no libName.so in java.library.path.The java.library.path does not include the folder where the dependencies were downloaded ($HOME_DIR.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201241.

Comment: Yes, looks like it. Thanks for the info.